# PCB w/ ESP8266 NodeMCU - Multiple SPI modules not working

Tags: arduino, pcb, spi, esp8266, rfid

I've been working on a project for quite a while now, which involves the
ESP8266 NodeMCU (v1.0), as well as two SPI Modules: ENC28J60, and
RFID-RC522. With that being said, I encountered a problem recently,
which I haven't been able to resolve so far. Working with
micro-controllers and electronics is still a learning experience for me,
so my knowledge here is limited. When I assembled the prototype for my
project on breadboards, everything was working fine in the end. So I
thought I can move on, and design my first PCB (ever).

After doing so, I quickly noticed that something is not working right:
When inspecting the serial output, I found out that only the
Ethernet-module (ENC28J60) has been recognized, whereas the
initialization of the RFID-module (RFID-RC522) didn't work out. My first
guess was, that the RFID-module was broken. After testing only the
module on the breadboard, the initialization of the RFID-module worked
out fine. Also, when only pluging the RFID-module into my PCB, it is
recognized without any problems.

After some research, I found out the problem might stem from the
SPI-lines on my PCB, as they should approximately have the same length
when working with high frequency devices, such as the ESP (
https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2019-tips-for-optimal-high-speed-spi-layout-routing
). So I designed another PCB, with exactly this condition (+ I also
tried to keep the SPI-routes short). When I soldered my newly designed
PCB, I still got no positive result. The problem stays the same.

Does anyone have an idea, why only one of the SPI-devices is recognized,
during initialization phase? The initialization of all the other devices
works fine. I have attached the schematics of my PCB-design to this
thread.

As a side information: I am using the LM3940 voltage regulator. When
measuring the voltage, I get almost exactly 3.3 V (as required by my
modules).

I would really appreciate any comment and help on this.

Please let me know if some information is missing. I will reply as soon
as I can.

[image: PCB schematic]

Comment: Why do you have Q2 on the ENC28J60 /CS signal?  What can you tell use about the differences between the working breadboard test and the non-working PCB?  You're also going to need to include your code, particularly the parts involved in the assignment of the SPI chip selects and the detection of the respective peripherals.

Comment: Ed S. - Welcome :-) (a) As commented by *Chris Stratton*, one of the standard troubleshooting approaches is to compare (in increasing detail) what works (breadboard h/w) with what fails (PCB h/w). There will be unavoidable differences, so skill & experience can help to prioritize the list of suspects. (b) I hope you have access to a scope (not, at first, a logic analyzer) to be able to compare the analog quality of relevant signals e.g. SPI on working vs. failing h/w. (c) All your resistor symbols are non-standard (varistor?). Is that a schematic error and the resistors are actually normal?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hello, thanks for your comment. (Edit) First question: For the prototype I needed a workaround to add the Eth-module to my project, as I had no more (CS) pins left [link](https://esp8266hints.wordpress.com/2018/02/13/adding-an-ethernet-port-to-your-esp-revisited/). Secondly, the only differences that come to mind are (1) I am no longer using any jumper cables/breadboards, and (2) I am powering the whole system over microUSB and a voltage regulator (instead of a adjustable power supply). All the other components used are the same.

Comment: @SamGibson Hello, thanks for the reply. To answer your questions: (a) Unfortunately I have already "destroyed" my breadboard-prototype over time (after documenting the schematic), as I needed some of the parts for other small projects. So I need some time to rebuild it (if necessary). I have noted the main differences to Chris in my comment, but most likely I lack experience to notice any other more detailed differences. (b) Unfortunately, I don't have access to a scope, maybe I'm lucky if I ask around. (c) The resistors are actually normal, I chose the wrong ones for my schematic.

Comment: The transistor does nothing to change the need of a /CS pin, really it doesn't seem to accomplish anything at all.  Sounds like there may be some mistakes there - how exactly are you driving that?   Driving the wrong chip select at the wrong time would easily explain your failures.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it has been a while when I connected the Ethernet module. I only remember that the usage of this transistor was necessary in order to get the Ethernet module working. Nevertheless, the Ethernet-Module does not cause any problems and when I built the prototype using exactly this schematic, both modules worked perfectly fine. But thanks for the tip! I will rebuild my prototype and check everything again, just to make sure the schematic is correct.